# Getting error after upgrade sitecore 7.5 to 8.0 Method not found: 'Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.CurrentInteraction"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I upgraded my Sitecore from 7.5 to 8.0 and when I tried to access my website; I got the following error:

> Method not found: 'Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.CurrentInteraction Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Session.CreateInteraction(System.Web.HttpContext)'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the assembly **Sitecore.Analytics.dll** has been copied to the `bin` folder in Website folder.

Those issues tend to arise when performing upgrade. Point to note here is to check the other Sitecore dlls with a vanilla Sitecore to make sure everything is up-to-date.

Comment: what is "vanilla" please share website

Comment: Sitecore vanilla is when you install a fresh Sitecore instance using the `exe`

Answer (score 0):

Compare to 7.5 many methods got deprecated in 8.0 sitecore.Analytics.dll and added couple of other dll wrt to analytics. If you have used those deprecated methods then you need to change in the code.